# Graphical object does not update as the xPosition updates

Tags: java, render, increment

I am trying to create a planet (blue circle), and have it move when i update the x-position. Here's the main class.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    public int width = 1400;
    public int height = (width/16)* 9;

    Dimension dim = new Dimension(width, height);

    JFrame frame;

    boolean running;

    NewBody earth;

    public Main(){
        this.setPreferredSize(dim);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void start(){
        running = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread(this, "display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double conv = Math.pow(10, 3);

        while(running){     
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if((now-startTime)/conv >= 1){
                earth.incXPos();
                startTime = now;
                return;
            }   

            update();
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        repaint();

    }

    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillOval(earth.xPos,earth.yPos, earth.radius*2, earth.radius*2);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main main = new Main();

        main.frame = new JFrame();
        main.frame.setResizable(false);
        main.frame.add(main);
        main.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.frame.pack();

        main.frame.setVisible(true);

        main.earth = new NewBody(0, 0,0, 50);

        main.start();
    }
}
```

And here is the NewBody blueprint, from which I am creating "earth"

```
public class NewBody {

    Main main = new Main();

    public int xOrigo = 1400/2;
    public int yOrigo = 800/2;

    public double mass;
    public double velocity;
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;
    public double force;
    public double vectorAngle;
    public double fx;
    public double fy;
    public double acceleration;
    public int radius; 

    public NewBody(double mass, int xPos, int yPos, int radius){
        this.mass = mass;
        this.xPos = xOrigo + xPos - radius;
        this.yPos = yOrigo + yPos - radius;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void incXPos(){
        this.xPos++;
    }
```

The problem is that when I run the program, the blue circle just stays in the same position, where it was initialized. It just flickers extremely fast, and nothing else happens. I am quite new to coding, and I do not seem to get any error message and therefore I do not know how to proceed. I have been stuck on this for some hours now.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `return;` statement in your `run()` method causes the method short circuits exit and thus quit immediately after calling `incXPos()` just once. This occurs even before `update()` is called and so `repaint()` is never called.

I'd do things a bit differently though:

- I'd draw in a JPanel
- I'd draw in its paintComponent method.
- I'd use a Swing Timer instead of a Thread to do my animation loop.
- I'd be sure to call the super's `paintComponent(g)` inside of my override.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleAnimation extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 1400;
   private static final int PREF_H = (PREF_W * 9) / 16; // do int mult **first**
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 13;
   private NewBody earth = new NewBody(0, 0, 0, 50);

   public SimpleAnimation() {
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

      // to allow for smooth graphics
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g2d.fillOval(earth.xPos, earth.yPos, earth.radius * 2, earth.radius * 2);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         earth.incXPos();
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleAnimation mainPanel = new SimpleAnimation();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleAnimation");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class NewBody {

   // !! Main main = new Main();

   public int xOrigo = 1400 / 2;
   public int yOrigo = 800 / 2;

   public double mass;
   public double velocity;
   public int xPos;
   public int yPos;
   public double force;
   public double vectorAngle;
   public double fx;
   public double fy;
   public double acceleration;
   public int radius;

   public NewBody(double mass, int xPos, int yPos, int radius) {
      this.mass = mass;
      this.xPos = xOrigo + xPos - radius;
      this.yPos = yOrigo + yPos - radius;
      this.radius = radius;
   }

   public void incXPos() {
      this.xPos++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hte input. Why does it short circuit? Is it because of the "return"-statement inside the while loop?

Okay, so you're suggessting I remove the canvas all together? Why is a JPanel better than a Canvas?

I'll look into swing timer, thanks! :)

Comment: @Arcthor: it short circuits because return exits immediately from the method. A while loop that loops exactly one time is not a very useful construct. Using the JPanel's paintComponent method gives you double buffering graphics by default.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Thank you! Really helpful. 

If you do not mind, I have one more question. Why should I not create a constructor to Main in NewBody? And if I can't do that, how do I access variables such as widht and height?

Comment: @Arcthor: if you create a new Main object in NewBody, it will be a completely new and unique object, one completely distinct from the original Main object, and that's not too helpful. If you need the Main instance in NewBody, you will want to pass the reference in, perhaps in a constructor.